# firefox addons panel hide

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, add-on

My addon opens a popup panel (popup.html).

When the user changes the current tab to different tab, the popup panel is hidden

When the tab is selected second time I need it to **still available** contentURL (popup.html) but I did find the way to do it.

Comment: If you think that my answer can help other users with the same problem in achieving what you wanted in this question, don't forget to accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create your panel like this:

```
<panel 
    id="yourPanel" 
    type="arrow"    
    noautohide="true"
    level="parent">      
</panel>
```

Explanation:

**level = "parent"** means the panel is shown just above the window the panel is in, but behind other windows above it.

**noautohide = "true"** means the panel will only be closed when the `hidePopup` method is called.

With these two combined, you get the behavior you're looking for.

For reference see [mdn panel page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/XUL/panel)